# get the edges within a list of nodes

Tags: python, networkx

How can I get all the edges whose both nodes are within a given list of nodes. `G.edges([list_of_nodes])` will return all the nodes where at least one node of each edge is in the `list_of_nodes` . I do not want that. how can i get it?

Comment: please give me clue about down vote?

Comment: Slight hint: "I do not want that. how can i get it?" Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't understand. Is it for less modesty? if is that so, my point of view is "I wrote that line to specify what I want to do and what I don't want to do. I thought, I should really clarify". Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop through all the edges you've found already and test if both nodes are in the list of nodes, but this is not optimal if the list of nodes is large.  Checking whether a list contains an element requires iterating through the list, so on average each edge takes `2*len(list)/2` checks [`len(list)/2` for each node].  Assuming the number of edges is proportional to `len(list)` this has quadratic time.

```
edges = [(u,v) for u,v in G.edges(list_of_nodes) if u in list_of_nodes and v in list_of_nodes]
```

A more efficient method would test if the nodes are in a set rather than a list.  Sets allow for very fast checking whether they contain an element.  It's almost `O(1)` per test.  So the full thing runs in linear time.

```
set_of_nodes = set(list_of_nodes) 
edges = [(u,v) for u,v in G.edges(set_of_nodes) if u in set_of_nodes and v in set_of_nodes]
```

Comment: I am doing the same. But it is very very slow as I have millions of edges.

Comment: are you using the `set_of_nodes` rather than `list_of_nodes`?

Comment: I started to use the list before your answer, that was very slow. Now i used set, it is very fast. Thanks you very much